# How can I execute some part of code once at a time in a concurrently running function?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord.py

So, let me give you a brief of what am trying to achieve. I've a command called `apply`, as soon as some one enters that command, execution of apply function begins. Now, apply function have some part of code which I want to be executed concurrently in case if many users triggered that command at the same time, and there is a async function called `register` which I want to be executed once at a time. Here's the glimpse of the code:

```
@client.command()
async def apply(ctx):
 #Stuff I want to be run concurrently
 await register(ctx.author)

async def register(user):
 # I've an another python file 'db.py' for accessing the database 
 data = await db.execute_query('SELECT Total_Reg from Data WHERE rowid = 1')
 total = data[0][0] # Getting the total registrations value and storing it in total variable     
 if total >= max_reg: # If total reg. are more or equal to max value then close the reg.
  print("Registrations are closed!")
  return
 # Otherwise if registrations are open then increase the value of total reg by 1
 # And register the user with unique registration number [reg_no] allotted to him
 await db.execute_query('UPDATE Data SET Total_Reg = Total_Reg + 1 WHERE rowid = 1')
 reg_no = total + 1
 registrations[reg_no] = user
 await close_registration() 
 """Also, in case of Queue or execution of this function once at a time, I 
    want this function to continue executing the code and shouldn't wait for 
    this line of code particularly, i.e await close_registration() should 
    keep on executing in background without blocking the current execution of 
    this function. So should I use asyncio.ensure_future(close_registration()) 
    instead of await or what?"""
```

I hope you get the idea what am trying to do here. Now, let's come to my query.
`apply` function is triggered by discord as soon as some one enters `apply` command, so there can be some case that `data = await db.execute_query('SELECT Total_Reg from Data WHERE rowid = 1')` can be executed multiple times at the same time which will cause the same number of registrations at that time to be returned and stored in total variable of all of them.

I know, sqlite locks the database when there is already a connection updating or accessing the database but then also, as soon as a query is executed, another will start executing there itself before `await db.execute_query('UPDATE Data SET Total_Reg = Total_Reg + 1 WHERE rowid = 1')` Increment query is executed.

What I want basically is,

This should be the order:

1. Getting the current number of registrations with  `data = await db.execute_query('SELECT Total_Reg from Data WHERE rowid = 1')`
2. Checking if registration is full or not
3. If not, then register the user and update the database by increasing the current no. of registrations by 1 with `await db.execute_query('UPDATE Data SET Total_Reg = Total_Reg + 1 WHERE rowid = 1')`

For example, if 2 users applied to register at the same time, then one should be registered first and then only another should get registered and `reg_no` for both of them should be unique.

So, that's it. How can I achieve this functionality? Should I use a Queue? Or is there any feature in sqlite to first get the current reg. and then increase the value by 1 if it's less than `max_reg` and all this in just a single query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well there possibly exists an SQL solution, but you could proceed with this with the help of discord.py

```py
@commands.max_concurrency(1, commands.BucketType.guild, True)
@commands.command() or #@bot.command() depends on what you are using
async def apply(ctx):
    #command here
```

`@commands.max_concurrency(number, bucket_type, wait)` lets you control the concurrency of the command.
`number` is the max number of times it can be used concurrently.
`bucket_type` is where the concurrency is supposed to be checked, guild means in a single guild, if you want it to be global use `commands.BucketType.default`.
`wait` is what it should do if someone uses the command and its not supposed to run. if we set it to true it will wait till the command finishes running, if wait is false it will raise an error which can be caught with an error handler.

If you just want a function to be executed once concurrently,

```
@commands.command(hidden=True)
@commands.max_concurrency(1, commands.BucketType.guild, True)
async def register(ctx, args):
   #do stuff
```

However people will be able to use register.

```
@commands.command()
async def apply(args):
   ctx.command = bot.get_command('register')
   await bot.invoke(ctx)
```

Very messy code, but should work.

### References:

- [max_concurrency](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=max_concurrency#discord.ext.commands.max_concurrency)
- [BucketType](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=max_concurrency#discord.ext.commands.max_concurrency)

Comment: I got you, but sorry I forgot to mention something i.e, this 'register' function is not triggered by the discord directly, there is a separate 'apply' function which is done so, and this  'register' function is called from that 'apply' function. Also, there is some part of code in 'apply' function which I want to be executed concurrently, but only 'register' function should be executed once at a time. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question, just in case you want to review again.

Comment: @Shubham, is client a `discord.Bot` instance or a `discord.Client` instance?

Comment: Client is an instance of `discord.Bot`

Comment: Any suggestions or solution to this problem?

Comment: You're not getting it, I only want the `register` function to be executed once at a time not the entire `apply` function. With your code, max concurrency of entire `apply` function is set to 1 while there is some part of code in this function which I want to be executed concurrently. Am requesting you to go through my question once again to have a better understanding.

Comment: In simple words, how can I execute some part of code in a concurrently running function once at a time? Not the whole function just some part of it.

Comment: You can wait till the function is completed, edited my code

Comment: Hmm I see, but this logic can be bypassed say in a case, more than 2 instances of apply function are running concurrently, so one instance of register function would be running at a time and other two would be waiting [In case of 3 instances] then as soon as the register function finished executing stuff and running_register is set back to False, then at the same time other instances can be triggered.

Comment: Say other instances are waiting in while loop and as soon as running_register is set back to False, more than one waiting instance can be triggered in a case where they check for while running_register at the same time. I hope you get me, I don't know how to explain this.

Comment: True. We can use discord's max_concurrency or implement the same ourselves, but that would be too large for a stackoverflow answer, you can take a look at how its implemented [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/cooldowns.py#L266-L316). I also edited my answer with a possible fix