# (Python) How can I access and update sqlite database at the same time?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

So, let me give you a brief of what am trying to achieve. I've a function which is triggered by discord on some event. It's as follows:

```
async def register(user):
 # I've an another python file 'db.py' for accessing the database 
 data = await db.execute_query('SELECT Total_Reg from Data WHERE rowid = 1')
 total = data[0][0] # Getting the total registrations value and storing it in total variable     
 if total >= max_reg: # If total reg. are more or equal to max value then close the reg.
  print("Registrations are closed!")
  await close_registration()
  return
 # Otherwise if registrations are open then increase the value of total reg by 1
 # And register the user with unique registration number [reg_no] allotted to him
 await db.execute_query('UPDATE Data SET Total_Reg = Total_Reg + 1 WHERE rowid = 1')
 reg_no = total + 1
 registrations[reg_no] = user
```

I hope you get the idea what am trying to do here. Now, let's come to my query. This function is triggered by discord, so can be execute parallelly or there can be some case that `data = await db.execute_query('SELECT Total_Reg from Data WHERE rowid = 1')` can be executed multiple times parallelly which will cause the same number of registrations at that time to be returned and stored in total variable of all of them.

I know, sqlite locks the database when there is already a connection updating or accessing the database but then also, as soon as a query is executed, another will start executing there itself before `await db.execute_query('UPDATE Data SET Total_Reg = Total_Reg + 1 WHERE rowid = 1')` Increment query is executed.

What I want basically is,

This should be the order:

1. Getting the current number of registrations with `data = await db.execute_query('SELECT Total_Reg from Data WHERE rowid = 1')`
2. Checking if registration is full or not
3. If not, then register the user and update the database by increasing
   the current no. of registrations by 1 with `await db.execute_query('UPDATE Data SET Total_Reg = Total_Reg + 1 WHERE rowid = 1')`

For example, if 2 users applied to register at the same time, then one should be registered first and then only another should get registered and `reg_no` for both of them should be unique.

So, that's it. How can I achieve this functionality? Should I use a Queue? Or is there any feature in sqlite to first get the current reg. and then increase the value by 1 if it's less than `max_reg` and all this in just a single query?

Thanks!

**Note:** Am using `aiosqlite` module for the database

Comment: You asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305720/discord-py-aiosqlite) two hours ago, please be patient and wait till someone answers it, there's no need to spam with the same question. Also `asyncio` runs things concurrently, not parallelly

Comment: Discord commands works in an event loop or they are executed parallelly? As, I've really felt this issue. Say, I tried reacting to an emoji [To Trigger this event] at the same time with my different phones, and it didn't worked. So, I thought discord commands works parallelly, also if they are not executed parallelly then how come we get sudden response through a command even in case where there are hundreds of people using that same bot in the same server? Just asking.

Comment: discord.py heavily uses the features that `asyncio` provides, so it runs commands/events concurrently. There's a difference between running things parallelly and concurrently, they're similar but not the same

Comment: Concurrently means running in a single thread by distributing time among the functions, like if one function is asynchronously waiting then other part of the code is executed, right? Also, what should I do in my case? I've explained my issue in the question.

Comment: No, Am still looking for an answer